# docker compose for php microservice

Tags: php, docker-compose, microservices, lumen, api-gateway

I want to build a restful API application using docker, Nginx, and Lumen that contains API gateway, microservices, and database container.

[image]

I need microservice that cannot be accessed from the internet and API gateway will communicate with microservice locally. How to set up docker-compose.yml to achieve this?

Comment: If you make a docker-compose.yml all services will be part of the same network. All containers inside the network can talk to each other **without exposing ports**. You only add the `ports:` config to the API Gateway, which will then be the only service reachable. https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/

Comment: so for API gateway and microservice I dont need config their nginx?

Comment: You will need to configure nginx to do authentication for you and/or to act as reverse proxy to "Service", but there is not special nginx config for exposing a port via docker. You can just use the names of the containers within the same docker network as hostnames and they will resolve to the correct IP that container has at that moment.